# Enoch and the Inclusion of the Gentiles

Tags: church-fathers, gentile, book-of-enoch

## Enoch and the Inclusion of the Gentiles

The [Book of Dream Visions](https://www.ccel.org/c/charles/otpseudepig/enoch/ENOCH_4.HTM), the fourth section of the Book of Enoch, closes with a summary of the history of Israel told in terms of animals. ([Wikipedia offers a short analysis.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch#Animals_in_the_second_dream_vision)) It closes with a vision of the Messianic Kingdom:

> And I saw that a white bull was born, with large horns and all the beasts of the field and all the birds of the air feared him and made petition to him all the time. And I saw till all their generations were transformed, and they all became white bulls; and the first among them became a lamb, and that lamb became a great animal and had great black horns on its head; and the Lord of the sheep rejoiced over it and over all the oxen. And I slept in their midst: and I awoke and saw everything.
>
> Enoch 9:37-39

This seems to describe the incorporation of gentiles (the animals of the field and birds of the air) into the Kingdom (they all became white bulls). They are not just subject to the Kingdom, but are a part of it and pleasing to the Lord (the Lord of the sheep rejoiced over it and over all the oxen).

It is widely accepted that Enoch influenced the early Church. Jude, 2 Peter, and possibly John reference it. Barnabus, Clement of Alexandria, Tertullian, Origen, Augustine, and others make use of it.

Do any of the Church Fathers (for the purpose of this question, assume the Patristic Age ends with John Damascene) make reference to this passage when discussing the inclusion of the gentiles into the Kingdom?

Answer (score 1):

The only meaningful references to the contents of its text are listed in the Wikipedia article on the [reception of the book of Enoch before modern times: in Christianity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reception_of_the_book_of_Enoch_before_modern_times#In_Christianity); as can easily be seen, they are rather rare and vague, being mostly restricted to [Jude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistle_of_Jude#References_to_other_books)'s and [Second Peter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Epistle_of_Peter#Content)'s use thereof.

[Philip Schaff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Schaff)'s English translation of the fathers of the first millennium can be found [here](http://www.ccel.org/fathers); one can easily download each volume in PDF format, and automatically search, by pressing `CTRL-F`, for the string *Enoch* in its text (because, even if the ancient authors were to sometimes omit explicitly naming the sources of their various quotes or references, the editors and translators usually add parentheses or footnotes detailing their ultimate origins, so one is bound to find it mentioned at least there).